# Best Value for Paid ASP.NET Controls

Tags: asp.net, controls, telerik

We have questions about free .NET libraries and applications, but I'm curious about what **ASP.NET control** packages you've used that provide the best bang for your buck. Yes, paid stuff.

I'll get the ball rolling by saying I love the [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax.aspx) controls, but their price tag isn't great. The one reason I would say the value is the greatest here because of the licensing, which makes deployment so easy.

Comment: Just make sure you get the source code in case there are bugs you can fix them with out relying on the Control developer.

Comment: Please make community wiki. Also add the telerik bit as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have both Telerik and DevExpress and I find myself, more and more, moving away from the Telerik stuff and using more of the DevExpress controls.  I particularly like the DevExpress reporting package (the Telerik one was unusable) and the Grid / PivotGrid.  However, Telerik does have better AJAX management helpers (although I no longer use them as I've learned enough about "raw" AJAX) and the Telerik Editor control is the best there is.

So...one vote here for DevExpress.

Comment: @Mark your experience seems to be more in line to mine, I really needed a lot from the ajax side of telerik, but once we started with jquery/json and ajax through from there, telerik stuff went gradually out of the mix

Comment: We use both the desktop application and asp.net controls from DevExpress. They aren't without their quirks and I tend to prefer asp.net mvc these days but if I had to use asp.net I would use DevExpress again.

Answer (score 4):

*[Full Disclosure: I work at Telerik.]*

I won't make any statements about which controls are the best- since clearly my opinions would be biased- but I will say that in the "3rd party" component market (in other words, not Microsoft and not open source) the pricing amongst the big players is all about the same. And in general, if you need the rich functionality offered by any of the 3rd party suites, the price is *significantly* lower than what you'd pay in your own dev time to rebuild the controls from scratch (or even to customize an open source control).

There are some significant differences in the way the licensing is handled, though, and as Josh originally highlighted, Telerik has the most open, "developer friendly" licensing approach. Purchased controls have *no* license keys to deal with.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Telerik is by far the most robust for the cost; but you're right that the cost is a bit high.

Comment: @Gortok I didn't have a good experience with it, althought I did neeed to get a lot from it on a project where it was the first time all the team was using it - jquery/ajax/json versions where always better :( - those were our first too at that time ... I guess we made some wrong uses, who knows.

Answer (score 2):

We use the "Web.UI" suite from ComponentArt and we're very happy with it.  You get the source code, redistribution, etc.  Makes our web app stand out for sure.

http://componentart.com

Answer (score 1):

The cost of Telerik's / DevExpress controls are CHEAP compared the cost having one or two people develop "something better".  I have had developers work two weeks on just a grid with no Ajax, no client side anything and it looked like crap.  Unless you have great skill with tools like jQuery and the team all possesses those skills, it is cheaper to go with a purchased library.  Stuck on an issue, open a ticket.  It's that simple.